# iPad running iPhone apps under iOS7 looks strange

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When running my iPhone apps developed for iOS6 on the iPad with iOS7 the window frame seems to be changed. Why does it not look the same as it does in the real iPhone 5 device.
Earlier the apps on iPad showed up in a 3.5" window with exactly the same look as in the device.
And an app made for a iPhone 5 with 4" display does not show up the same in iPad any more.
It seems to be not tall enough leaving an area on top of the app window. So if the view background it set to white, it will be a white "bar" on top. It is not the case in a real 5" device where it looks ok as earlier.
And if I have a search bar, the window will be visible over and coming up behind the search bar if I scroll the window upwards. Like the frame was not set to the same ratio as the iPhone. Why and what to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation yet? about the transition from iOS 6 -iOS 7?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174